# Reduce/shrink JAR size of Java Project that uses JNA?

Tags: java, jna

I'm hiding a specific window using JNA which works fine, but i need to shrink my whole project. I guess there are a lot of things in JNA which i dont need.
Is there a way / tool which removes all the things never called in case of the following main method programatically? I've all the JNA classes inside my project, not just the common jar file.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class HideHwnd {
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
      int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
      boolean ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int i);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
      user32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
         public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg1) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText);

            if (wText.isEmpty()) {
               return true;
            }
            if (wText.startsWith("window1")){
                if (user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, 1))
                    System.out.println(wText+" is hidden now!");
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: Are you talking about shrinking the size of your JAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had great success with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), although I have not tried it with any JNA-projects:

> ProGuard is a free Java **class file shrinker**, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It **detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes**. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.

The obfuscating can be entirely disabled and ProGuard will scan class-file dependencies and omit unused classes ("classes to keep always" can be specified). ProGuard *can* be used on external libraries as well and used to build a single JAR with only the "required classes".

Answer (score 1):

You can also safely eliminate any native libjnidispatch.so/.dll within jna.jar for platforms you don't intend to support.